# How to show following is weakly sequentially compact.

Tags: measure-theory, compactness, compact-operators, uniform-integrability, orlicz-spaces

I have defined the integral operator on a finite measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ Orlicz space $T: L^{\Phi}\to L^{\Psi}$, suppose we have the result that says for any bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$, $\{Tf_n\}$ is uniformly integrable. Now I want to know is there any way to show that $\{Tf_n\}$ is weakly sequentially compact?